# C# accessing a class when using codefile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application project, in visual studio 2017. We are using codefile, instead of code behind, on the server, so this project can be sheared with organisations who do not have visual studio.

Within the visual studio project, I have created a class, so I can reuse code on every page (to do with controlling who can access certain pages).

Therefore, on each web page, page_load event, I have the following code:-

```
generalFunctions objSecurity = new onlineCaseReporting.generalFunctions();
if (!objSecurity.userAllowedToAccessPage(pageFileName))
{
```

This works perfectly, within visual studio on my development machine but on the server, I get the following error:-

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'generalFunctions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am assuming this is because I am using CodeFile and not supplying any DLLs. Is there a way to use classes when using CodeFile?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to deploy your code either as an assembly (DLL) or source file (.cs) in the bin folder or app_code folder respectively. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx).

Comment: Brilliant, the app_code folder idea worked. Thanks.